# Deploying ojdbc14.jar in a code module for a FileNet code module

Tags: oracle, deployment, websphere, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I'm trying to **deploy** a couple of **jar files in a code module** for an event action in **FileNet P8 4.0** (the FileNet server runs on **WebSphere 6.1**). One of these jars is my custom code, and the other jar is the thin driver for **Oracle** called **ojdbc14.jar** (I also tried with **ojdbc15.jar**), the custom code uses the oracle jar in order to connect to a data source and get a connection using the **JNDI** name.

When the event action is executed (after a subscription is invoked) the code in my custom module is called OK, the problem occurs when my code needs to **load classes** from the Oracle jar, I get this cause:

**ERROR - Mon Sep 21 16:42:17 UTC 2009 -** **com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]**
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookupExt(Helpers.java:1000)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processSerializedObjectForLookup(Helpers.java:705)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.processResolveResults(CNContextImpl.java:2093)

...

**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleLog**
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.dbutils.impl.OracleUtilityImpl.setLogVolume(OracleUtilityImpl.java:85)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalOracleDataStoreHelper.setProperties(InternalOracleDataStoreHelper.java:142)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.(WSRdbDataSource.java:846)
        at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.setDataSourceProperties(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1947)
        ... 43 more

...

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleLog**
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:496)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:132)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:87)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:597)
        ... 48 more

Since I'm deploying the oracle jar with the code module, ***shouldn't FileNet should be able to find the class? Do you think I need to configure something else?***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - ojdbc14.jar is pretty old now (meant for Java 1.4 [4]) I would upgrade to ojdbc5 or ojdbc6.jar depending on your build environment (unless of course you are actually still using Java 1.4).

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I tried ojdbc5.jar, and I still get the same problem, at least we can say the problem is not this jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... somehow the ojdbc14.jar file got corrupted, so even when the classpath was correct and no matter what I tried to fix the problem, the problem was always there.

Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for your application to use WebSphere's own JDBC connection pools? When you set up a pool for a particulr database you get all the vendor-specific drivers installed there.

Generally, all manner of classpath and classloader confisions ensue when you try to place infrastructure code in your own applications. I don't know for certain that this is the case for your situation, but I do find taht staying on the known path in WebSphere tends to give the smoothest results.

Comment: Thanks djna, I will take your suggestions in account. The root cause of my problem was that the ojdbc14.jar was corrupted and somehow the ojdbc5.jar file was also corrupted.

Thanks!